# How is encoded data sent over a network?

Tags: networking, base64, traffic

I'm a bit confused how people represent binary data, and how it is sent over networks. I will explain through Wikipedia's example. Shown here <- https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxsfc.jpg -> So I have my binary data encoded as base 64, and I am sending the text TWFU. So I am sending T then W then F and finally U. But to send T, a char. I will need one byte to send it, like I've always been told. One character sent over a network is one byte.

Because now I've come to think that if I encode 24 bytes, I will be sending over 4 characters, but to send over 4 characters I need the same amount of bytes as characters??

So when sending over the network `"Man" (unencoded) (Requiring 3 bytes normally)` vs `"TWFu" (encoded) (requiring 4 bytes normally)` in the example from above, are the same sequence of bits sent over the network the same. Because the last time I've used a socket to send over data, they just ask for a string input, never a text + encoding input.

Answer (score 4):

Synopsis: "How" is an agreement. "Raw" is common.

---

Data is sent in whichever way the sender and receiver agree. There are many protocols that are standard agreements. Protocols operate at many levels. A very common pair that covers two levels is TCP/IP. Many higher-level protocols are layered on top of them. (A higher-level protocol may or may not depend on specific underlying protocols.) HTTP and SMTP are very common higher-level protocols, often with SSL sandwiched in between.

Sometimes the layers or the software that implements them is called a stack. There is also the *reference* (or *conceptual*) [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). The key point about it is that it provides a language to talk about different layers. The layers it defines may or may not map to any specific stack.

Your question is too vague to answer directly. With HTTP, "raw" binary data is transferred all the time. The HTTP headers can give the length of the body in octets and the body follows the header. As part of the agreement between the sender and receiver, the header might give meta-data about the binary data using [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) headers. For example: Your gravatar 
[image] is sent with headers including:

```
content-length:871
content-type:image/png
```

That's enough for the receiver to know that the sender claims that it is a PNG graphic of 871 bytes. The receiver will read the header and then read 871 bytes for the body and then assume that what follows is another HTTP header.

Some protocols use synchronizations methods other than bodies with pre-declared sizes. They might be entirely text-based and use a syntax that allows only certain characters. They can be extended by a nesting agreement to use something like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to represent binary data as text.

Some layers might provide data compression of sufficient density that expansion by higher layers, such as Base64, is not a great concern. See [HTTP Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), for example.

If you want to see HTTP in action, hit F12 and go the Network tab. If you want to see other protocols active on your computer try [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html), [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/MessageAnalyzer/), [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is a method for encoding arbitrary 8-bit data in a purely 7-bit channel. As much as the internet is based on the principle of 8-bit bytes, for text mode it's presumed to be 7-bit ASCII unless otherwise specified.

If you're sending that data Base64 encoded then you'll literally send `TWFU`. Many text-based protocols use Base64 out of convenience: It's an established standard and it's efficient enough for most applications.

The foundation of the internet, IP, is a protocol based on 8-bit bytes. When sending binary data you can make full use of all 8 bits, but if you're working with a text-mode protocol, of which there are many, you're generally stuck using 7-bit ASCII unless the protocol has a way of specifying which character set or encoding you're using.

If you have the option to switch to a "binary" transfer then you can side-step the need for Base64. If you're working with a 7-bit ASCII protocol then you're probably going to need Base64.

Note this isn't the only method for encoding arbitrary binary characters. There's also [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) as used in email, and [URI encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for URLs. These are more efficient in cases where escaping is exceptional, but far less efficient if it's required for each character.

Comment: So you're saying that I send over the network "TWFu", which requires 4 bytes. Once is it over the network, the person decodes it? I'm just failing to see the point of encoding something requiring MORE characters. In there example they could send "Man" over the network, requiring 3 bytes. But they encode it to "TWFu" requiring 4 bytes. I don't see the point in this, once it's sent over the network, the person is decoding it and a lot of bytes are ignored? `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64` Reading from the first example here.

Comment: You normally don't encode 7-bit ASCII but you would for binary content that have to be compatible with legacy systems. Email, as one example, uses Base64 for attachments to ensure the email itself is merely plain-text, easily processed. Decoding is the responsibility of the recipient and is usually dictated by the protocol or standard in question. The bytes aren't "ignored", I'm not sure where you're getting this impression.

Comment: The key thing here is that text-mode protocols, of which there are many, generally require 7-bit encoding as per the ASCII standard. Newer text-based encodings (e.g. JSON) use UTF-8, which is 8-bit, but still can't contain arbitrary binary data because in UTF-8 the highest bit has significant meaning for multi-byte characters. Base64 is a 6-bit encoding and does a pretty good job of utilizing *most* of the plain-text characters in the ASCII standard. Remember 0 through 31 are reserved as "control characters" which have special meaning, like line-feed and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're dealing with 7-bit text only there's no need for base-64 encoding.

However, if you'd need to send

```
Man
Boy
```

over a purely 7-bit text channel you couldn't send it as literal with the line breaks. Instead, you'd send encoded in base64

```
TWFuDQpCb3kNCg==
```

which has encoded line breaks but doesn't use incompatible characters. Of course, the receiver needs to know that you're sending encoded text - either implied by the protocol or explicitly marked in some way.

Comment: I'm confused where you and the other poster are getting this 7-bit from, 7-bit channel? Not sure what you mean

Comment: Many application protocols can only use 7 bit and are unable to transmit/receive full 8-bit data, e.g. SMTP or IMAP. Imagine sending a binary JPEG image with a typewriter.